# Query returns a few extra records

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have these tables and this query in an Access database:

samples

```
hole_id    | depth_from | depth_to  |
DH001        100          105
DH001        105          120
DH001        110          115
DH001        115          120
```

overlapping_samples (and therefore the correct output)

```
hole_id    | depth_from | depth_to  |
DH001        110          115
DH001        115          120
```

query

```
SELECT a.*
FROM samples AS a
INNER JOIN overlapping_samples AS o
ON a.hole_id=o.hole_id
WHERE a.hole_id=o.hole_id AND a.depth_to=o.depth_to
;
```

results

```
hole_id   | depth_from | depth_to  |
DH001       100          105
DH001       110          115
DH001       115          120
```

It's very simple. The result is almost ok, but it includes some extra records from the left table (i.e. samples). In fact, in the example above it may not necessarily return the extra row. Only a small percentage are.

If not obvious, I want to return all the records from the left table that match to the right table. The right table is actually a subset of the left, and therefore the query should have the same number of records. It's intended for a DELETE statement, but

Comment: Have you tried `INNER JOIN ... ON a.hole_id=o.hole_id AND a.depth_to=o.depth_to AND a.depth_from=o.depth_from` and remove the where clause?

Comment: what is the desired output?

Comment: The desired output is the same as overlapping_samples table. I have stripped the extra data out and this is for the purposes of deletion in the left table (samples).

Comment: @SebastianSiemens I had not thought of like that. It does change the results, but now I have fewer records than expected. Why?

Comment: INNER JOIN on all 3 pairs of fields should be most efficient. All of the suggestions return two records. If that is not what you expect, then provide table of expected output. Perhaps need a larger data sample.

Answer (score 0):

this may work:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM samples a
JOIN overlapping_samples o ON a.hole_id = o.hole_id
WHERE a.depth_from = o.depth_from 
  AND a.depth_to = o.depth_to;
```

I fixed a problem in WHERE clause, from:

```
a.hole_id=o.hole_id
```

to:

```
a.depth_from = o.depth_from
```

`hole_id` is already present in `JOIN ... ON a.hole_id = o.hole_id`

if you still don't get correct count you may need to look at your data and add some extra condition either in WHERE or JOIN clause

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Also, "this may work" reads like "I did not even bother to verify my code in any way". Understandably that is not easy without a [mre] by OP. So ...

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Comment: So I did try a combination of these, forgot to say. This particular one only returns 25 records out of 161. I don't understand why. I have manually checked some of the data to confirm that what I expect is in the table.

Comment: Sorry, the question is vague, my answer fixed obvious mistake in the query in `WHERE` clause, query looks correct now but without better problem description I assume that it "may" work

Answer (score 0):

i've changed your query to:

```
SELECT a.hole_id as ahole_id, a.depth_from as adepth_from, a.depth_to as adepth_to,o.hole_id as ohole_id, o.depth_from as odepth_from, o.depth_to as odepth_to
FROM samples AS a
LEFT JOIN overlapping_samples AS o ON a.hole_id=o.hole_id AND a.depth_to=o.depth_to AND a.depth_from=o.depth_from
WHERE a.hole_id=o.hole_id AND a.depth_to=o.depth_to;
```

and it gave me this result

```
ahole_id    | adepth_from   | adepth_to | ohole_id  | odepth_from   | odepth_to |
DH001       110             115          DH001       110                115
DH001       115             120          DH001       115                120
```

is that what you were looking for?

Comment: The `id` and `to` fields are already linked in JOIN clause, not necessary to also link in WHERE clause. Use `a.*` and `o.*` to simplify pulling all fields.

Comment: in that case there will be extra rows with NULLs, and my approach always been with selecting fields by their names. but there is up to personality

Comment: I'm going to have to go sift out some original data and use that instead. The results are weird. Not every hole gets an extra record, just some. My example is just simplified for this. This result in a much-reduced set of records. Kind of like only row 1 is returned.

Comment: @June7 Yes but the left table does have other fields, they are just not relevant to the example.